# Alert if JSON Data is Empty - Code not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I want to check if json data is empty or not.

if json its empty, i want to alert `orders Not Found`.
If its not empty, i want to alert  `orders found`.

if user not logged in, there won't be any token in his localstorage. so he will get a 500 error when browser requests the API URL. then I want to  alert `failed` along with the `failed status reason`

my dev is sick, so tried my self. its not going too well.

Tried the below code, not at all working.

```
<script>             
$http.get("http://localhost.com/activeorders/?format=json",{
            headers: {'Authorization': 'Token '+ localStorage.getItem("token")}})
                .success(function(response) {

                    if(response=="[]")
                    { 

                        alert(" orders NOT found");


                    }
                    else
                    {   

                        alert("orders  found"); 
                    }

                    .error(function(response,status) {

        alert("failed");
    alert(status);
                }
                 return ;
            }); 

</script>
```

Any help will be thankfull.

Comment: Debug your empty responce. If it comes like responce.data where data should be array, than check array length. If data is object - check for any own property presented

Comment: Check with If(response.length ===0)

Comment: can you put your response log here. maybe you handling it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are trying to do in **Angular js**, then you can try the code below using **callbacks**:

```
 $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost.com/activeorders/?format=json',
      headers: {
          'Authorization': 'Token '+ localStorage.getItem('token')
      }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){ // this callback will be called asynchronously when the response is available
          if (response.data.length == 0){
              console.log("orders NOT found")
          }
         // or if you just return an array json by php for example
          //if (response.length == 0) {
              //console.log("orders NOT found")
          //}           
      }, function errorCallback(response){ // called asynchronously if an error occurs or server returns response with an error status.
          if (response){
             alert("failed");
          }
      });
```

If you are using an external file .json type, you can try :

```
menuApp.controller("dynamicMenuController", function($scope, $http) {
$http.get('config/menu.json').success(function(data) { 
    console.log("success!");
    if(data.length == 0){
        alert('empty');
    }
    else {alert('some here!')}
});
```

If your json is in another domain, an external domain . In this case , I suggest you look at JSONP instead, here's an example http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js//consuming-external-services/consuming-jsonp-apis.html:

```
 $http.jsonp('http://teckstack.com/api/get_recent_posts/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK').success(function (data) {
    console.log("success callback");
    if(data.length == 0){
       alert('empty');
    } // response data 
}).error(function (data) {
    console.log("failed callback");
});
```

Comment: It is **necessary to make sure** that your webservice method is returning a json with the correct header .

Comment: thank you. but seems not to be working  :( . check - http://pastebin.com/2uvePTsn

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if a JS object or JSON is empty (`{}`), for example, your object is `response`:
`Object.keys(response).length === 0 && response.constructor === Object`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
if( Object.keys(JSON.parse(response)).length == 0 ){
  alert("err")
}
```

Comment: its response.data.lenght

Comment: go for the official documentation.. check the script.js in the last example here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http